# `FSolve` error when running matlab code in python using `Oct2py`

Tags: python, matlab, octave, oct2py

I have a matlab function which uses `fsolve` built-in function.
It works well on matlab side.
When I try to run that matlab function in python using `Oct2py`, I face this error.

[image: error]

[image]
Please help me with this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error indicates that the way you've called `fsolve` is wrong somehow. Since you don't provide any code, there is not much more to say here. When other people use fsolve, typical errors include passing a 'call to a function' instead of a 'function handle'.  (e.g. `fsolve ( myfun, x0 )` instead of `fsolve( @myfun, x0 )' )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a code clip.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, you are calling fsolve with 6 input arguments [instead of the expected 3](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Solvers.html).

You say your code 'works' in matlab, but from the equivalent matlab documentation [I don't see matlab being compatible with more than 3 arguments either](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html). It is possible that your extra arguments simply get ignored in matlab. What are `Xp`, `q`, and `in_param` supposed to do?